# mat-cell same width of mat-header-row

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, material-design

I have a very simple `<mat-table>` with lots of columns, where sometimes data is missing.
Anyway each `<mat-cell>`'s width does not match its own relative `<mat-row-header>`'s width, neither when the data/content width is greater than the header's one.
I've already looked up on internet without success.
Thank you so much for your help.

[The actual, broken table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfEKh.png)

I expect the width of all cells of the same column and the column's header (the row-header) itselt to all have the width equal to the maximum content's width among all contents on those cells.

Comment: OttinaAlmavivaSpA please share the minimal reproducible code for this issue, if possible a working stackblitz with the issue replicated!

Comment: Sadly, this is a Industry-private software, replicating the situation via an MRC could not be possible. Anyway, I'll update the question if I would do it. Thanks!

Comment: Open stackblitz with a mat table example on angular material website, then try to compare both the code copy paste only the configurations not the data until you are able to reproduce the issue, best case secnario you solve it yourself, or you post the question here!

Answer (score 0):

mat-table uses flex layout for columns, you can control this columns with style classes

```
.mat-column-customName {
    flex: 0 0 15%; /* percentage based on your columns number */
}
```

or set a min width

```
.mat-column-customName {
    min-width: 100px; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your sharing! Sadly, I've already tried it, without success. This suggests me that the actual problem lies somewhere else, like some CSS rules making some interference of some kind.